# Make a circular button programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uikit

I want to create a circular  `UIButton` in my `iOS` application.

The button is for creating a profile picture for the user.

This is the circular profile picture:

[image]

And this is how it looks like after a picture was chosen:
[image]

You can see that the button is too big and not circular.
This is my code:

```
func setUpProfilePicture() {
        profileIcon = UIImage(named: "characteer")!
        profilePicture.setImage(profileIcon, for: .normal)
        profilePicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profilePicture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSelectedPhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.view.addSubview(profilePicture)
        
        profilePicture.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profilePicture.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profilePicture.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -180).isActive = true
        profilePicture.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        profilePicture.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    }
```

The chosen picture should be just filled in the circle of the profile picture character image. I worked with auto layouts, so the most tutorials I found didn't help me!

Thank you! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust UIButton's layer:

```
profilePicture.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let cornerRadius = 25 // 50 * 0.5
profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: It is still not a circle:( but it's smaller

Comment: I think you should mark my answer as correct, because in mine the corner radius will change based on the button (so other people can easily copy my answer)

Comment: @TLGCodin' I can, not a big deal, but in your case frame has to be calculated. so you have to use constraints or check that frame is not zero, otherwise force layout.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the corner radius of your `UIButton` to be half of it's size

```
profileIcon.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
profileIcon.layer.cornerRadius = min(profileIcon.frame.height, profileIcon.frame.width) / 2
profileIcon.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically:

```
private extension UIView { 
    func willCircle() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width) * 0.5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

- usage: `profilePicture.willCircle`

---

Storyboard:

```
@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry bro but it doesn't work! There is nothing happening